# What are the Doctor and Clara doing in the opening of “The Caretaker”?

Tags: doctor-who

In the opening scene of ***The Caretaker*** (S08E06), we see the Doctor and Clara cuffed on a desert planet.

How did they get there? What are they doing there? Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: I don't think this needs a spoiler tag. It's literally in the opening scene of the episode.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At the risk of saying "[that's the joke](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NoodleIncident)", that is quite literally the joke. At the start of the episode we're shown a few snippets of Clara's (amazing) adventures with the Doctor, interspersed with her (mundane) relationship with Pink.

There's no specific explanation how they escaped, other than that she managed to get off the planet with little more than an unexplained suntan.

The BBCAmerica [show synopsis](http://www.bbcamerica.com/anglophenia/2014/09/doctor-recap-caretaker/) simply refers to this as the...

> *"...demands of her life with the Doctor— all sand piranhas and near-death
>   experiences"*

Answer (score 3):

There was a sequence showing them in various places. This was just to signify that they had been on a series of adventures. We're not really supposed to know any detail (apart from some brief mention later in the episode).

Answer (score 2):

It's similar to when the Doctor and Martha are shown going after something that is hatching, armed with bows and arrows, in Blink. We don't know the details, what is being shown is that there are other adventures and events than the ones we see on the screen.  (We may learn more later, or not.)